# How to apply formatting subroutine in module to various ranges across workbook

Tags: excel, vba, module, formatting

I made a formatting sub within a module I'd like to call to various ranges across the workbook. I am getting 424 error for applying an invalid procedure to my range object.

In the module, I have:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BoldRedFont(rng As Range)

With rng.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .Size = 10
    .Color = -16776961
    .Bold = True
End With

End Sub
```

In the worksheet, I have:

```
Option Explicit


DynamicSpreadsRange()

Dim pasteCell As Range
Set pasteCell = Range("B5")
pasteCell = "Paste spreads here"
BoldRedFont (pasteCell)

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove these parenthesis - `BoldRedFont (pasteCell)` - Subroutines do not use them. Functions do. That is not a function, because it does not return anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of using sub routines over functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539838/purpose-of-using-sub-routines-over-functions)

Answer (score 0):

As @braX mentioned in comment you can't use BoldRedFont (pasteCell)

But you can use it like this with Call:

```
Call BoldRedFont(pasteCell)
```

or previously mentioned (without parenthesis)

```
BoldRedFont pasteCell
```

Also i suggest using attributes of range (and other objects) when you want to write value into range then use *(when you send parameter to your BoldRedFont function it is correct because you want to send there whole range)*.

```
pasteCell.Value = "Paste spreads here"
```

I hope this clarifies it a bit.